# Performing cross-platform calls to php from Qt5

Tags: php, c++, qt, user-interface

I'm developing a Qt desktop GUI.

I need to be able to run:

`php myWonderfulScript.php parameter` from the Qt app.

php is available on the command line on my development computer, however it's unlikely to be available on the user's computer. I also need `php5-curl` installed...

Can I reliably distribute php .so/.a/.dll files with my Qt desktop application so it will run on Mac/Windows/Linux? (I know there are big licensing issues that arise in this situation and I will be sure to not steal anyones work)

I'm using Qt Creator 3.1.2 (based on Qt 5.3.1)

Comment: You can require an installed and configured php as a pre-requisite, as an option.

Comment: Sure, but that's not really an option for a consumer product (many of whom are Windows users). It's hard enough to get them to enter their payment details let alone "download and install PHP" (and also make sure that php-curl is available). Ideally I'd like a one download/one install scenario that is simple, quick and idiot-proof.